# Using Rails form helpers with Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

I'm trying to build a new Rails app with MongoDB using Mongoid as the ORM. The authentication is handled by the sorcery gem.

I'm getting the following error in my Users#new view.

`undefined method 'password_confirmation' for #<User:0x007feff2a23890>`

My model looks like this.

```
class User                                                                                                                                                              
 include Mongoid::Document                                                                                                                                             
 authenticates_with_sorcery!                                                                                                                                           

 attr_accessible :username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation                                                                                                  

 field :username                                                                                                                                                       
 field :email                                                                                                                                                          
 field :password                                                                                                                                                       
end
```

I get this error if I don't have a `field` definition in the model for each field. The `password_confirmation` field is a virtual field, so it shouldn't have a `field` definition anyway. How do I use dynamic and virtual fields in Mongoid (which are set to true in the config) with form helpers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add:

```
attr_accessor :password_confirmation
```